# Cannot navigate to the detail view in UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, ios6

I am trying to navigate to the detail view in the UITableView and seem to have some problems in executing it.

My code:

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>{
    NSArray *tableItems;
    NSArray *images;

}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray *tableItems;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray *images;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize tableItems,images;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    tableItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Item1",@"Item2",@"Item3",nil];
    images = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"clock.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"eye.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"target.png"],nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return tableItems.count;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    //Step 1:Check whether if we can reuse a cell
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    //If there are no new cells to reuse,create a new one
    if(cell ==  nil)
    { 
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyleDefault) reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
        UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] init];
        v.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = v;
        //changing the radius of the corners
        //cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10;

    }

    //Set the image in the row
    cell.imageView.image = [images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //Step 3: Set the cell text content
    cell.textLabel.text = [tableItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //Step 4: Return the row
    return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    cell.backgroundColor = [ UIColor greenColor];
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    SecondViewController *detailViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];

    [detailViewController printRowNumber:indexPath.row+1];

    //NSArray *dataItem = [self.tableItems objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    //detailViewController.dataSource = dataItem;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    //[self presentViewController:detailViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
@end
```

SecondViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController{
    IBOutlet UILabel *lbl;
}

-(void) printRowNumber:(int)num;

@end
```

SecondViewController.m

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void) printRowNumber:(int)num{
    lbl.text = @"Hello";
    NSLog(@"%d",num);
}
@end
```

I am able to print out the value of the indexPath.row in the output, but not able to show the detailview of the SecondViewController. Not sure what the problem is. Need some guidance...Thanks..

Comment: Do you get any error? What happens when you tap on a table row?

Comment: No error, i am able to print the value of the indexPath.row but i am not able to go into the detailview...

Comment: Just to confirm - are you sure the main viewcontroller is embeded in navigation controller?

Comment: no... it is not embedded in a navigation controller. How to do that?

Comment: u can't use a view-based application?

Comment: If you are using storyboard, select your viewcontroller and there is a menuitem `Embed In` - select navigation controller in that

Comment: Have a look at this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341337/embed-navigation-controller

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18693/discussion-between-lakesh-and-user427969)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this:

[embed navigation controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341337/embed-navigation-controller)

You need to embed your `mainViewController` in a `NavigationController`, if you want to use `pushViewController:` method.

If you do not want to use the `NavigationController` then you can use `presentViewController:` method to load the `detailViewController` and `dismissViewController:` method to return to the `mainViewController`